# Why does css3 multi-column layout's float causes element's width to be equal to one column's width in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a problem with multi-column layout. I've designed menu as group of div elements that I want to align into 1-4 columns (depending on screen height and menu items count). It cannot be hardcoded.

Here's my HTML ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/1qpsubr9/3/)):

```
<nav id="sideMenu" class="side-nav">
    <article class="side-nav-content">
        <div class="content-box-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="box-header pre-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-header">
                    <p>Option1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-header post-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <a>Link1</a>
                    <a>Link2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="box-header pre-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-header">
                    <p>Option1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-header post-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <a>Link1</a>
                    <a>Link2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="box-header pre-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-header">
                    <p>Option1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-header post-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <a>Link1</a>
                    <a>Link2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="box-header pre-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-header">
                    <p>Option1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-header post-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <a>Link1</a>
                    <a>Link2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="box-header pre-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-header">
                    <p>Option1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-header post-box-header"></div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <a>Link1</a>
                    <a>Link2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <p class="wrong">This should be on the right side of mneu.</p>
</div>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
p, a {
    color: black;
}

#sideMenu {
    float: left; /*This float seems to mess up column layout's width*/
}

article.side-nav-content {
    -webkit-column-width: 255px;
    -moz-column-width: 255px;
    column-width: 255px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 28px;
    -moz-column-gap: 28px;
    column-gap: 28px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    height: 200px;
}

.side-nav .content-box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 0px 0px 23px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 255px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

.content {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}

.wrong {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}

body {
    width: 200vw;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

If you inspect #sideMenu in browser you'll see that despite the fact that it is visible as 3 columns and should have their width it only has first column width.

How can I fix this? (The red text should be next to the last box on the right side)

[image: image with issue]

Removing float is not a a good solution since I need this next to page content.

I need menu div to float as well as page content since I want my menu to slide back and forth on user's click. I want to modify menu width on user's action from 0% to 100%, but that's not possible since the content interferes with menu. I have tested that with newest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: How about setting a "clear: both" rule for the ".content" elements in your CSS stylesheet

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem, @user2340218.

Comment: Then try adding "display:inline-block" and "width: nn%" rules, for your "#sideMenu" element while keeping its "float:left" rule

Comment: Didn't help either. I think I will go with transform: translateX(-100%); for showing / hiding menu, but that won't work while I have issue mentioned in question.. Any more ideas? Maybe column layout is supposed to behave this way and it's written in some standard? I just don't see why give an option to only set column width (without specifying column count), but implement browsers in such a way that element has wrong width...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the only way I came up with is with javascript. (since the column width will be dynamic based on the amount of content in the column div and the window size).

So the #sideMenu has to have "position: relative;" and then in the javascript you set the style.left to be at least the width of the column container which you can get by document.getElementById('columnContainer').clientWidth.

I can provide a jsfiddle or more code here if you need.

you will have to call the javascript function onbody load and anytime widow size changes, at least.

Good luck

Comment: If you can please provide a jsfiddle and/or paste some code here. I tried to do this on my own, but I see that column-gap is not displayed correctly (is way more that 28px).

Comment: after trying to get my idea to work with your fiddle - I think you should consider using css flex for you use case - it's really much better.  In my case, and IMHO I think the only reason to use css columns is with regular text to get a news-paper columns effect. But in your case css flex boxes should be much easier to solve your problem. Please let me know if you want to be show some sample code for you.